# Rudin's RCA chapter 10 exercise 16

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying Rudin's RCA chapter 10 and get in trouble with exercise 16.

$\phi(z,t)$ is defined on $\Omega\times X$ where $\Omega$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$ and $X$ is a measure space with complex measure $\mu$. $\phi$ is holomorphic function of $z$ for each $t$, and measurable function of $t$ for each $z$. Moreover, $\phi$ is a uniformly bounded function.

Define $f(z)=\int_X\phi(z,t)d\mu(t)$.

The problem is to prove that $f$ is holomorphic.

I solved the problem with Morera's theorem, but I want the solution with the hint from Rudin: Show that to every compact $K\subset \Omega$ there corresponds a constant $M<\infty$ such that $|\frac{\phi(z,t)-\phi(z_0,t)}{z-z_0}|<M$ ($z$ and $z_0\in K$, $t\in X$)

I can complete the solution if i have the hint, but i can't prove the hint.

Comment: That doesn't follow from being holomorphic in $z$?

Comment: I'm not sure it is a uniform bound for both z and t.

Comment: + the fact that $\phi$ is uniformly bounded.

Answer (score 1):

For showing holomorphicity it suffices to show the bound for $z$ close to $z_0$. There is $r>0$ so that $B(z_0,r)\subset \Omega$ and $|\phi(z,t)-\phi(z_0,t)|\leq 2\|\phi\|_\infty$ for $|z-z_0|<r$. It follows (Schwarz' Lemma)  that for those $z$'s:
$$\frac{|\phi(z,t)-\phi(z_0,t)|}{|z-z_0|} \leq \frac{2}{r}\|\phi\|_\infty $$
The claim is also true for general $z_0,z\in K$ since the previous holds for uniform $r>0$ and shows that $\phi$ is uniformly locally Lipshitz. This may then be extended globally.